# nmap/netcat differentiate between open port with no service listening and open ports with a service listening

Tags: netcat, nmap

I'm pretty new with networks scanning and test tools (nmap and netcat). I want to know how to differentiate :

- if a port is opened in a host **with a service listening on this
  port**
- If a port is opened and in host **without no service listening
  on this port**

How to differentiate these two situations on results of nmap and/or nc commands ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the service is not listening you'll get a connection refused message.

Example

```
# no service listening
$ nc -vz 127.0.0.1 22
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connection refused.

# service listening
$ nc -vz 127.0.0.53 53
Ncat: Version 7.80 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 127.0.0.53:53.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.03 seconds.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @madrisan !